# jQuery Table Sorter Build Widget Pager

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making table with JQuery TableSorter Build Widget, but I have no idea how to add a pager.

I added this `.tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val() })` to my javascript code, but it doesnt work.

This is my code

```
    var contacts = {
    //debug: true,
    widthFixed: true,
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    "widgetOptions": {

        "build_type": "json",
        "build_source": {
            "url": "http://sms.apiconn.com/dev/contacts/results.json",
            "dataType": "json"
        }
    }
};

//console.log(opts);

$('#contacts').tablesorter(contacts).tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val() });
```

And this is where table is made

```
<div id="contacts"><?php getContacts(); ?></div>
```

Another question is how can I make that table refreshes?

Function 'getContacts' builds JSON file every time page refreshes.

Comment: Add your html code after it was echoed... and isnt the element initialized by tablesorter suppose to be the table itself? http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html

Comment: I have added html code after it, but it doesnt work

Comment: no i mean to your question, add the end html, not the php code that generates it

Comment: I have added end html from this page https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html

Comment: instead of `$('#contacts')` try passing the table element

Comment: I added it, it works on page where table is not loaded with JSON but with PHP function. I will try this method - https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html